# update panel not working

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajax.net

i am having two list box which perform add remove item functionality which are controlled by four buttons and o  each button click there happen to be post back but i don't want it to be flicker for which i am using update panel like this but it still made post back wats wrong with this explain me this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="button" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text=">" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click"  Width="50px"/><br />
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonRemove" runat="server" Text="<" OnClick="ButtonRemove_Click" Width="50px"/><br />
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddAll" runat="server" Text =">>>" OnClick="ButtonAddAll_Click" Width="50px"/><br />    
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonRemoveAll" runat="server" Text ="<<<" OnClick="ButtonRemoveAll_Click" Width="50px"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote a quick example that does work.  You do not need your buttons in the `UpdatePanel`.  You only need the `ListBox` since they are the only controls being refresh.  Setup the `Trigger` for the `UpdatePanel` will cause the refreshes to occur without the '*flicker*'.

aspx code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text=">" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click"  Width="50px"/><br /> 
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonRemove" runat="server" Text="<" OnClick="ButtonRemove_Click" Width="50px"/><br /> 
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddAll" runat="server" Text =">>>" OnClick="ButtonAddAll_Click" Width="50px"/><br />     
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonRemoveAll" runat="server" Text ="<<<" OnClick="ButtonRemoveAll_Click" Width="50px"/>     
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="button" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonAdd" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonRemove" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonAddAll" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonRemoveAll" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
        </ContentTemplate> 
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

cs (codebehind) code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Test1", "1"));
        ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Test2", "2"));
        ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Test3", "3"));
        ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Test4", "4"));
        ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Test5", "5"));
    }
}

protected void ButtonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListBox2.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBox2.SelectedItem);
        ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox2.SelectedIndex);
        ListBox2.ClearSelection();
        ListBox1.ClearSelection();
    }
}

protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem);
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex);
        ListBox1.ClearSelection();
        ListBox2.ClearSelection();
    }
}
```

I have tested this and it does work.  I only implemented 2 of the `Button`s to present a complete example.

Comment: 2 years later and it's the exact answer I needed! XD

Comment: My bad, I was too excited running off and using the code. Upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `asp:ListBox` to the `ContentTemplate` of your `asp:UpdatePanel`, or add a new `asp:UpdatePanel` and add it to its `ContentTemplate`. The control won't be updated using an asynchronous postback if it's not placed within an `asp:UpdatePanel`.

With the following code snippets the newly added `listBox` will be updated with new content using an asynchronous postback:

*Page.aspx*:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="button" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text=">" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" Width="50px" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonRemove" runat="server" Text="<" OnClick="ButtonRemove_Click"
            Width="50px" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddAll" runat="server" Text=">>>" OnClick="ButtonAddAll_Click"
            Width="50px" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonRemoveAll" runat="server" Text="<<<" OnClick="ButtonRemoveAll_Click"
            Width="50px" />

        <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="listBox"></asp:ListBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Sample event handler in the code-behind file, *Page.aspx.cs*:

```
protected void ButtonAddAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox.DataSource = new List<string>() { "Test" };
    listBox.DataBind(); 
}
```

Comment: i have already put all my code in update panel but still it flicker  
i dont under stand y so

Answer (score -1):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="button" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text=">" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" Width="50px" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonRemove" runat="server" Text="<" OnClick="ButtonRemove_Click"
            Width="50px" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddAll" runat="server" Text=">>>" OnClick="ButtonAddAll_Click"
            Width="50px" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonRemoveAll" runat="server" Text="<<<" OnClick="ButtonRemoveAll_Click"
            Width="50px" />

        <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="listBox"></asp:ListBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```